# получить адрес функций OpenGL в линуксе

Tags: c#, linux, opengl

есть такой метод для получения адреса метода на c#

```
[DllImport("opengl32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr wglGetProcAddress(string name);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryA(string name);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr module, string name);

private static IntPtr GetAnyGLFuncAddress(string name)
{
    IntPtr p = wglGetProcAddress(name);

    if (p == (IntPtr) 0 ||
       (p == (IntPtr) 0x1) || (p == (IntPtr) 0x2) || (p == (IntPtr) 0x3)||
       (p == (IntPtr) (-1)) )
       {
          IntPtr module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
          p = GetProcAddress(module, name);
       }

     if (p == IntPtr.Zero)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("метод: " + name + " ненеайден");
     }

     return p;
}
```

как сделать тоже самой под линукс?

Answer (score 1):

1. [dlopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)   ≈   `LoadLibrary[A/W]`.
2. [dlclose](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlclose)  ≈   `FreeLibrary`.
3. [dladdr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr)   ≈   `GetProcAddress`.

Вам еще стоит много чего прочитать прежде чем начинать работать с данным функционалом, если вы не работали с динамической загрузкой `shared object` файлов в `Linux`.

Comment: а какой файл является аналогам  `opengl32.dll`?

Comment: думаю то что вам необходимо https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/Linux